# Understanding cat << ! syntax

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to Bash scripting. I came across [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/159522-sendmail-html-body-attachment.html) link and noticed an unusual syntax for cat.

```
cat << !
HOPE THIS WORKS
This sample E-mail message demonstrates how one can attach
files when sending messages with the Unix sendmail utility.
!

uuencode ${file_1} ${file_1}
uuencode ${file_2} ${file_2}
uuencode ${file_3} ${file_3}
!
```

What does the << mean? What does the ! mean? How come the cat has an opening and closing !, but uuencode doesn't?

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the help! The last outstanding question I have is why is there no opening and marker for the uuencode section. From what I'm understanding, cat has a `<< !` indicating it's a HEREDOC. `uuencode` however doesn't seem like a HEREDOC. What gives?

Comment: It is called [here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells). Just a strange marker

Comment: That looks like a heredoc, but that last `!` confuses me.

Comment: The last `!` just looks like a typo; it should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called heredoc, and its constructed like this:

```
command << MARKER
Literal text here, can contain $variables
and newlines,
    leading spaces
    and tabs... 
MARKER
```

And works with everything between the `MARKER` is going as stdin to the specified command. What marker you use is optional and in your example `!` is being used. And if you feed the command `cat` with input on stdin it will simply print it to stdout:

```
cat << !
all this text will go to stdout
!
```